# How can I create a function that has when called, an addOnSuccessListener could be added to it

Tags: android, kotlin

Not sure how to phrase this question. I would like to create a function, that when called, I can add `addOnSuccessListener` to it before continuing to the next one.

I know that when I have the function return a `Task<Void>` I can add to it the `addOnSuccessListener` but in the function itself, I am not sure what to return, as the operation I am executing is a simple process of saving EditText input into variables. Not sure what Task to return.

This is my function:

```
fun saveInput(): Task<Void> {
    email = emailInput.text.toString()
    phone = phoneInput.text.toString()
    whatsApp = whatsAppInput.text.toString()

    return //notSureWhatToReturnHere
}
```

And I want to be able to do something like this:

```
saveInput.onSuccess{
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
class Worker<T> {
    private var successListener: ((result: T) -> Unit)? = null

    fun onSuccess(result: T) {
        successListener?.run { this(result) }
    }

    fun addSuccessListener(listener: (result: T) -> Unit): Worker<T> {
        successListener = listener
        return this
    }
}

class MyRandomClass {
    fun doSomething(variable: String): Worker<String> {
        val worker: Worker<String> = Worker()
        val result = variable.reversed()
        worker.onSuccess(result)
        return worker
    }
}
//... in code
val randomClass = MyRandomClass()
randomClass.doSomething("Hello World")
    .addSuccessListener {
        Log.d(TAG, "Result is: $it")
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a hard time understanding how to incorporate that into my code (beginner). I've added my current code that I think might explain it a bit better. Is there something I can pace in my current code to fulfill this purpose?